# How to insert a comma separated values to the column to a SQL table in a order same as passing order?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i written a code like below to insert a comma separated values to the tempTble.It is working but i need the values to be entered in a order same as am passing it to query.But here number are arranged in a numerical order and string values arranged according to alphabetical order .Example '7,6,5,1,2,Jack,Ana,Micky' but it is inserted to column in a order of '1,2,5,6,7,Ana,Jack,Micky'.

Can you please provide answer for this.
Thank you in advance

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetValuesFromBillingSystem]
(
@BillingSystemCode VARCHAR(max)
) 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @planID varchar(max) = Null ;

SET @planID= @BillingSystemCode
DECLARE @tempTble Table (planID varchar(50) NULL);
while len(@planID ) > 0
begin
insert into @tempTble (planID ) values(left(@planID , charindex(',', @planID +',')-1))
set @planID = stuff(@planID , 1, charindex(',', @planID +','), '')
end
select * from @tempTble 

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/07/sql-server-split-function-example-in.html

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))

RETURNS @Results TABLE (Items nvarchar(4000))

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @INDEX INT

DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)

-- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z
--     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP

SELECT @INDEX = 1

WHILE @INDEX !=0

BEGIN

-- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER

SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)

-- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE

IF @INDEX !=0

SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)

ELSE

SELECT @SLICE = @STRING

-- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET

INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)

-- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING

SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)

-- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE

IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK

END

RETURN

END
```